# Determining the 5 integers in sequence in ArrayList with largest last integer

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have a sorted ArrayList of integers with no duplicates:

`ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15));`

Assume it is guaranteed that there is a sequence of at least 5 numbers in the list.

I'm trying to determine the 5 number sequence with the largest last number.  In this case, it would be:

`[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` (the order of this result doesn't matter to me)

This is what I came up with:

```
public class Game {

    public static void test2(ArrayList<Integer> al) {
        ArrayList<Integer> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.reverse(al);
        System.out.println("list before: " + al);
        for (int i = 1; i < al.size(); ++i) {
            if (al.get(i) == al.get(i - 1) - 1) {
                newArrayList.add(al.get(i - 1));
            }
            if (newArrayList.size() == 5) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("new list: " + newArrayList);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15));
        test2(al);
    }

}
```

This yields the following list:

`[15, 12, 11, 10, 9]` instead of `[12, 11, 10, 9, 8]`

I know why my solution doesn't work but can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution which:

- uses an `isValid` helper method to analyze the current and candidate sublist.
- makes use of `subLists` to avoid having to create separate ones (sublists show a view of the main list so elements aren't copied).
- avoids reversing the parent list by iterating backwards.

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4,5,16,17,18,19,22,23,24,47,48,90);
```

Check for solutions of series containing 1 to 5 elements.

```
for (int limit = 5; limit > 0; limit--) {
     System.out.printf("For limit = %d : %s%n",limit, getMax(list, limit));
}
```

prints

```
For limit = 5 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
For limit = 4 : [16, 17, 18, 19]
For limit = 3 : [22, 23, 24]
For limit = 2 : [47, 48]
For limit = 1 : [90]
```

The main routine that iterates thru the subLists of size limit and returns either the valid one or `null` if not found.

```
public static List<Integer> getMax(List<Integer> list, int limit) { 
    for (int i = list.size()-limit; i >= 0; i--) {
        List<Integer> candidate = list.subList(i,i+limit);
        if (isValid(candidate)) {
            return candidate;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Returns `true` if the candidate is a valid arithmetic sequence of size `limit`. Else returns `false`.

```
public static boolean isValid(List<Integer> candidate) {
    for (int i = candidate.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (candidate.get(i) - 1 != candidate.get(i-1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is a very creative solution.  Thank you!  I also figured out another solution (which I'll post as another answer), but I like yours more.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but I figured out a solution.

```
public static void test2(ArrayList<Integer> al) {
        ArrayList<Integer> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.reverse(al);
        System.out.println("original list: " + al);
        for (int i = 1; i < al.size(); ++i) {
            if (al.get(i) == al.get(i - 1) - 1 ) {
                newArrayList.add(al.get(i - 1));
                if (i == al.size() - 1 || newArrayList.size() == 4) {
                    newArrayList.add(al.get(i));
                }
            } else {
                newArrayList.clear();
            }
            if (newArrayList.size() == 5) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("new list: " + newArrayList);
    }

original list: [22, 21, 20, 16, 15, 14, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2]
new list: [12, 11, 10, 9, 8]
original list: [11, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
new list: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
original list: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2]
new list: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
    public static void determineGreatestFiveCardsInSequence() {
        List<Integer> list = List.of(2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12);

        int start_index = 0;
        int end_index = 0;
        int length = list.size();

        for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
            if (list.get(i - 1) + 1 != list.get(i)) {
                end_index = i - 1;
                if (end_index - start_index >= 4) {
                    break;
                }
                start_index = i;
            }
        }
        if (!(end_index - start_index >= 4)) {
            end_index = length - 1;
        }
        System.out.println(list.subList(start_index, end_index + 1));
    }
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15));
    ArrayList<Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4));
    ArrayList<Integer> al3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(45, 23, 214, 123, 12, 67, 45, 23, 546, 234, 12, 23));
    test2(al);
    test2(al2);
    test2(al3);
}

public static void test2(List<Integer> al) {
    System.out.println("list before: " + al);
    
    Integer maxValue = al.get(4);
    Integer maxValuePosition = 4;   
    for (int i = 5; i < al.size(); ++i) {
        if (al.get(i) > maxValue) {
            maxValue = al.get(i);
            maxValuePosition = i;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("max value position: " + maxValuePosition);
    
    List<Integer> newArrayList = al.subList(maxValuePosition - 4, maxValuePosition + 1);
    System.out.println("new list: " + newArrayList);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't yield the expected outcome.  newArrayList is `[10, 11, 12, 14, 15]` instead of `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`.  All 5 integers in the sublist have to be consecutive.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Your evident problem is lack of knowledge on how to debug.

Given that you asked this question on SO, evidently you think a seasoned programmer just stares at code for a while in a zen-like trance and then jumps out the bathtub, run down the street, and yell eureka a lot.

That's.. not how it works.

You debug. It's easy! You arrange a system whereby you can see what your code is doing as it is doing it, and you work out 'in your head' or on paper what you think it should do.

Anytime the two disagree, yay! You found one (1) bug. There are probably more; fix it, start over or keep going. Once the software does exactly what you expected it to do, grand. It works now. Ship it.

So, go ahead, and do that. It's generally a good idea to learn how to use debuggers (they make this easy by letting you see the value of expressions and variables, and run code one line at a time), but if that sounds like too much effort right now (that's not good; you may have heard that laziness is a virtue - that's not the kind of laziness you want to cultivate), in which case, there's always injecting a boatload of Sysout statements.

I specifically suggest you check what happens to `newArraylist` when the 'subsequence of 5' you are gathering together ends up failing halfway through, i.e. 15 - check, 14 - still check, 12 - uhoh, turns out 15 was **not** the final number in the 5-number sequence you were looking for after all. So, now what does your code do when this scenario occurs?

Don't think about it. Just go edit your code so your code *tells you* what it does in that case. Contrast to what you want it to do, and, you'll have your answer.